# A Figure in beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, graphs, trees

Can anyone please tell how can I produce the following figure in `beamer` :

[image]

Comment: Some people take exception to questions of the form "Please draw this for me". You will get more help if you post some code showing what you have tried and give a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: To speak frankly, I don't know what is the figure called. I thought it a flowchart but no flowchart matched like this. Latex is not like other programming language that I will write my own `function`.

Comment: Oh, I must know what the figure is called. This is a *"tree diagram"*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## graphdrawing

Using TikZ `graphdrawing` (needs LuaLaTeX).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphdrawing}
\usegdlibrary{trees}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \graph[
    tree layout,grow=right,fresh nodes,
    nodes={draw,fill=lightgray,rounded corners}
  ] {
    Patients -> {
      Treatment $A_1$ -> {
        Treatment $B_1$,
        Treatment $B_2$
      },
      Treatment $A_2$ -> {
        Treatment $B_1$,
        Treatment $B_2$
      }
    }
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

## forest

Or you may use `forest`.  (Thanks to @cfr for the hint about `parent anchor=children,child anchor=parent`)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={grow=east,parent anchor=children,child anchor=parent,
    draw,fill=lightgray,rounded corners}
  [Patients
    [Treatment $A_1$
      [Treatment $B_1$]
      [Treatment $B_2$]
    ]
    [Treatment $A_2$
      [Treatment $B_1$]
      [Treatment $B_2$] 
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

## tikz-qtree

You could also abuse `tikz-qtree` (which is actually for linguistic trees)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  grow'=right,level distance=3cm,
  every node/.style={draw,fill=lightgray,rounded corners}
  ]
  \Tree [.Patients
    [.{Treatment $A_1$}
      [.{Treatment $B_1$} ]
      [.{Treatment $B_2$} ]
    ]
    [.{Treatment $A_2$}
      [.{Treatment $B_1$} ]
      [.{Treatment $B_2$} ]
    ]
  ]
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

## ConTeXt MkIV

If you don't know what ConTeXt is, you can stop reading.

I used the [`charts`](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Flow_Charts).

\noheaderandfooterlines

```
\usemodule[chart]

\setupFLOWcharts
  [
    width=9\bodyfontsize,
    height=2\bodyfontsize,
    dx=1\bodyfontsize,
    dy=0pt,
  ]

\starttext

\startFLOWchart[treatment]
  \startFLOWcell
    \shape    {action}
    \name     {pat}
    \location {1,4}
    \text     {Patient}
    \connect  [rl]{tA1}
    \connect  [rl]{tA2}
  \stopFLOWcell

  \startFLOWcell
    \shape    {action}
    \name     {tA1}
    \location {2,2}
    \text     {Treatment $A_1$}
    \connect  [rl]{tA1B1}
    \connect  [rl]{tA1B2}
  \stopFLOWcell

  \startFLOWcell
    \shape    {action}
    \name     {tA1B1}
    \location {3,1}
    \text     {Treatment $B_1$}
  \stopFLOWcell

  \startFLOWcell
    \shape    {action}
    \name     {tA1B2}
    \location {3,3}
    \text     {Treatment $B_2$}
  \stopFLOWcell

  \startFLOWcell
    \shape    {action}
    \name     {tA2}
    \location {2,6}
    \text     {Treatment $A_2$}
    \connect  [rl]{tA2B1}
    \connect  [rl]{tA2B2}
  \stopFLOWcell

  \startFLOWcell
    \shape    {action}
    \name     {tA2B1}
    \location {3,5}
    \text     {Treatment $B_1$}
  \stopFLOWcell

  \startFLOWcell
    \shape    {action}
    \name     {tA2B2}
    \location {3,7}
    \text     {Treatment $B_2$}
  \stopFLOWcell
\stopFLOWchart

\FLOWchart[treatment]

\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) An entire survey! If you add `parent anchor=children, child anchor=parent` to `for tree` in the Forest example, the edges will be drawn from the points indicated in the OP's image.

Answer (score 3):

And one alternative with ordinary tree :-) :

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
      every node/.style = {draw=gray, rounded corners, fill=gray!10, inner sep=2mm},
         level 1/.style = {sibling distance = 22mm},
         level 2/.style = {sibling distance = 11mm},
         level distance = 33mm,
                   grow = right,
edge from parent/.style = {draw, thick, ->},
  edge from parent path = {(\tikzparentnode.east) -- (\tikzchildnode.west)},
                        ]
  \node  {Patients}
    child { node {Treatment $A_1$}
        child { node {Treatment $B_1$}}
        child { node {Treatment $B_2$}}
          }
    child { node {Treatment $A_2$}
        child { node {Treatment $B_1$}}
        child { node {Treatment $B_2$}}
          };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Closer to the OP picture:

[image]

Source:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[grow' = right,
                 line width = 1.5pt,
             level distance = 44mm,
          every node/.style = {shape = rectangle,
                               minimum size = 13mm,
                               text width = 24mm,
                               rounded corners = 2mm,
                               draw,
                               fill=black!10,
                               align=center,
                              },
             level 1/.style = {sibling distance = 36mm},
             level 2/.style = {sibling distance = 17mm},
                              ]
      \node {Patients}
      child {node {Treatment $ A_1 $}
        child {node {Treatment $ B_2 $}}
        child {node {Treatment $ B_1 $}}}
      child {node {Treatment $ A_2 $}
        child {node {Treatment $ B_1 $}}
        child {node {Treatment $ B_2 $}}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```